# (noun + verb) data vs (nount + verb) THE data

Tags: grammar, articles

In an example sentence, "the" was excluded on the sentence "[Noun + verb] data". But I think "the" should be included. Can anyone please confirm and enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: They are both grammatical and idiomatic. They mean different things and would be used in different contexts.  Without knowing your context it is impossible to say which is right for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Do not delete data” = do not delete **any** data.

“Do not delete THE data” **The** data =

1. that data that I, you, or we have already spoken of.
2. that data that someone else has told us both about.
3. that data of which we are both, from experience, already aware.
4. that data which I am now, or will be, indicating.
5. that data to which I am now, or will be, referring.

Please bear in mind that if you approach a stranger in the street and say

(A) "**The** cat is trapped", he will look at you as if you were mad. He will reply: "Which cat are you talking about?"

(B) "A cat is trapped", he will understand and be concerned. He will reply: "Where is it trapped?"

(C) "**The** moon is bright." He will understand and agree with you, because everyone knows of the moon.

The is used to qualify words that have been specified or that both the speaker and listener are aware of.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that you are correct in your statement, "the" should be included.
"Data" is very broad, whereas specifying which data could be needed.

Both statements are correct, the context is just necessary to be correct.

E.g Are you deleting the specified data?
or
Are you deleting all data?

Comment: "Do not delete data" could also mean "Do not delete _any_  data" . This would be the same form as "Do not drop litter".

Comment: @user741630 Only if you are talking about some specific, predefined data. If you say "Calculate the forecast from the research but do not delete the data" this means that you should not delete the research data. If you say "Do not delete the data" without specifying which data you're talking about people will probably ignore your instruction.